# How to email current page of pdf document on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, email, pdf

i made a library app that contains pdf files.
i used fastpdfkit for reading pdfs.

but there is no solution for sending just one page of pdf file.

is it possible to email current page of pdf file, not whole document?.

Answer (score 0):

if you want an image to 1 page you could use this

```
UIImage *currentPage = [UIImage drawCurrentView:currentPageNum];
```

This is the drawCurrentView :

```
+(UIImage*)drawCurrentView:(NSUInteger)currentPageNum
{

NSString *filePath = //Your PDF Path

CGSize resultImageSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);//For iPhone

CFStringRef pathRef = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, [filePath UTF8String],
                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, pathRef,
                                                 kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
CFRelease(pathRef);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);

CFRelease(pdfURL);
CGPDFPageRef myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf,currentPageNum);

// get the rect of our page
CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);

// create a new context for resulting image of my desidered size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resultImageSize);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);

// translate so the origin is offset by exactly the rect origin
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -resultImageSize.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, resultImageSize.width /pageRect.size.width,resultImageSize.height/ pageRect.size.height);

// now draw the document
CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

// generate image
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf); 

return resultingImage;
}
```

Comment: what is drawCurrentView? there is no method for UIImage.

Comment: oh im sorry @fulberto100 i didnt past all code .. please check my edit.